# How to consume non-angular server HATEOAS endpoints with Angular2?

Tags: rest, autocomplete, angular

I want to provide a simple autocomplete functionality. As a frontend I plan to use Angular2. As a Backend I got spring-mvc based HATEOAS restfull API. I want the frontend to provide the autocomplete based on the CRUD provided byy the REST API. 
I want the rest api results to be displayed as a autocomplete list.

E.g.
user typed: *empl_*

autocomplete return list of options (based on HATEOAS):

- employees create
- employees list
- employees add
- employees remove
  etc.

### Question:

1. How to implement it with Angular2 efficiently i.e. so that user would not suffer form long load of the autocomplete list?
2. Is the Angular2 enough or should I use some other third party technology eg.caching/indexing or rather stateful (like meteor)?

Comment: One thing you could try is using an angular 1 HATEOAS package  https://github.com/jmarquis/angular-hateoas  and upgrade it to angular 2 http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using Angular 2.0's reactive programming capabilities for this job. Something like:

```
this.searchResults = Observable.from((<EventEmitter>this.searchText.valueChanges).toRx())
   .debounceTime(200)
   .switchMap((val:string) => myService.load(val))
   .merge(this.clear.toRx().mapTo([]));
```

More details on [this](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3010853/application-development/up-close-with-googles-angular-2-javascript-framework.html)  post, under 'Reactive programming' section. There are plenty of examples for this task from the reactive programming world.

Hope it answers your question